# WebStorm cannot find file, open WebStorm in terminal

Tags: linux, angular, terminal, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Opening WebStorm in terminal

Version: WebStorm 2016.3.3

The only reason why I'm guessing it's not working is because I have emojis in some of my files name. Do you think that's why, and if not then where does the problem lay?

Does emojis mess with filenames?

[image: click for image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is indeed caused by emojis. Please follow [IDEABKL-7421](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7421) for updates